# R, GLM model: Selection of significant variables from full model

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I need to run a GLM and have tried to select the significant variables with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153497/selecting-the-statistically-significant-variables-in-an-r-glm-model) approach. However, I keep getting an error message.

The input is:

```
global.model2<-lm(Percent_Mite._rel_abundc ~ Heightc + logNutrientsc + logNDSc + logNNNc + logOxygenc + Patchc + Precipitationc)
```

Then I run

```
Select <- summary(global.model2)$coeff < 0.05
```

resulting in

```
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        TRUE      FALSE    TRUE    FALSE
Heightc            TRUE      FALSE    TRUE    FALSE
logNutrientsc     FALSE      FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
logNDSc            TRUE      FALSE    TRUE     TRUE
logNNNc           FALSE      FALSE   FALSE     TRUE
logOxygenc         TRUE      FALSE    TRUE    FALSE
Patchc            FALSE      FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
Precipitationc     TRUE      FALSE    TRUE    FALSE
```

Next:

```
Relevant <- names(Select)[Select == TRUE]
```

Here, the result is

```
NULL
```

and the following command

```
sig.formula <- as.formula(paste("Percent_Mite._rel_abundc ~",paste(Relevant, collapse= "+")))
```

results in the error message

`"Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :
    <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: Percent_Mite._rel_abundc ~ 
   ^`

What am I doing wrong? Some of the variables should be significant.

Comment: I think you want `Relevant <- names(Select)[Select[ ,4] == TRUE]`.

Comment: can I recommend (1) `sig.formula <- reformulate(Relevant,response="Percent_Mite._rel_abundc")` instead of your current `sig.formula` call (2) **not doing this at all** for statistical reasons (e.g. see [here](http://www.danielezrajohnson.com/stepwise.pdf) ?

Comment: You can. Statistics is really not my field and every hint I can get is greatly appreciated. What would you do with the dataset at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are operating on a matrix but the code is assuming a vector. I believe that you want to produce the Boolean vector and not return the entire table of coefficients.

```
( Select <- summary(global.model2)$coeff[-1,4] < 0.05 )  
( Relevant <- names(Select)[Select == TRUE] )
```