# R - remove specific terms from GLM

Tags: r, regression, polynomials

I have a following generalized linear model (part with coefficients was removed as it's not significant for this question)

```
Call:
glm(formula = time ~ I(nDOF^3) + I(ndoms^2) + I(nDOF^2) + (poly(I(1/nprocs), 
    2) + poly(nnodes, 2) + nDOF + ndoms)^2, family = gaussian(link = "log"), 
    data = dataFact)

(Intercept)                            ***
I(nDOF^3)                              ***
I(ndoms^2)                             ***
I(nDOF^2)                              ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)1                  ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2                  ***
poly(nnodes, 2)1                       ***
poly(nnodes, 2)2                       ***
nDOF                                   ***
ndoms                                  ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)1:poly(nnodes, 2)1 ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2:poly(nnodes, 2)1 ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)1:poly(nnodes, 2)2 ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2:poly(nnodes, 2)2 ** 
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)1:nDOF             ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2:nDOF                
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)1:ndoms            ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2:ndoms            ***
poly(nnodes, 2)1:nDOF                  ***
poly(nnodes, 2)2:nDOF                     
poly(nnodes, 2)1:ndoms                 ***
poly(nnodes, 2)2:ndoms                 ** 
nDOF:ndoms                             ***
```

t-test shows us, that `poly(I(1/nprocs), 2)2:nDOF` and `poly(nnodes, 2)2:nDOF` are not significant and I'd like to remove them from the model. I don't want to write down all the interactions by hand.

Is there any simple way to remove them in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the statistically significant variables in an R glm model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153497/selecting-the-statistically-significant-variables-in-an-r-glm-model)

Comment: @MārtiņšMiglinieks I'm afraid the problem is with using `poly` - command `sig.formula <- as.formula(paste("time ~",relevant.x, collapse= "+"))` then doesn't work.